# how to make horizontal scroll view of images .?

Tags: iphone

i am new developer on iphone and i am working on a project. the problem i am having is that i have no idea about how to create a horizontal scroll view of images. what i want is that when i click on the table view containing image thumbs, i should view the same image in a much larger size and scroll the other images that are on the left and the right.

Answer (score 2):

The class you want is UIScrollView. You can add multiple UIImageViews to a UIScrollView.

In addition to ScollingMadness recommended by luvieere, check out Apple's UIScrollView sample code which is referneced from the Xcode UIScrollView documentation.